# How to redirect 301 non-www to www nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, vhosts

im using nginx and i want to redirect non-www to www. im edit file from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myweb`. im follow step from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/redirecting-non-www-to-www-in-nginx?answer=14783 and im create something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ainocloud.com;

    return 301 $scheme://www.ainocloud.com$request_uri;
}

server {
 root /var/www/html;
server_name www.ainocloud.com;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

but its not working.

Comment: Are you hitting your non-www url as http or https ?

Comment: @ben5556 https....

Comment: its work when im not use https, but when with https its not redirect.

Comment: It's working as expected then because your first server block only redirects non-www to www if it's http (port 80). To make it work with https add `listen 443 ssl;` and configure ssl certificates as described here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: so i have to add more server { listen 443; ....} ?

Comment: No, you can listen on 80 and 443 in the same server block as described here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server BUT you need to configure the server ssl certificates

Comment: @ben5556 ok ill try it...

Comment: @ben5556 its redirect to www but not redirect to https https://github.com/jazuly1/nginx/blob/master/ainocloud

Comment: @ben5556 u can try access ainocloud.com

Comment: Why do you have 3 server blocks ? Ideally for your non-www to www redirection for both http and https you only need one server block.

Comment: @ben5556 im not create it, i think lets encrypt build it.

Comment: I just tested `http://ainocloud.com` and `https://ainocloud.com` -> both are redirecting to `https://www.ainocloud.com/` and I see a Welcome to nginx! page so looks like its working ?